# how to do the Click event on each bargraphs or pie chart using dojo

Tags: dojo

I have bar graph and pie chart using dojo graphs.

I need to keep the click event on each bar and pie chart slice to get the value of that particular slice or bar?

Comment: NO body knows this answer? please update me if any body knows?
thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on "keep the click event on each bar and pie chart slice" --- what does it mean exactly? Did you try actions?

Comment: Hmmm First commnet for Eugene Lazutkin.. I am not scaring potential helpers sorry for if you all mean like that.. :)

Comment: I have a pie chart and Bar grpahs displayed nicely in page.. Now My manger is asking me to do like.. if you click on pic chart on slice...
you need to show data in the grid in other page..
so I need to implement Click event on each pie chart or each bar grpash so that I can go to databse to pull the information about perticular pie slice or bar please let me know if you dint understood anything

thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stuff is actually documented:

- The official doc: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html#chart-events
- The test for events: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_event2d.html